# Mousedown on body and drag the page up or down, like on a pdf

Tags: jquery, scroll, drag

How would I make it so I can mousedown on the body on my page, then drag the page up or down, like you can in a PDF?

Basically I want to be able to drag the whole page up and down, any idea how to do this? I don't want to use jQuery UI for anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, here are the stages...

1) You need to have a constant listener on the body of the document that will keep tabs on the current mouse position

2) On mouse down you will need to scroll roughly equal to the mouse movement (you could choose to scroll slightly faster)

Here is an example of doing this in jQuery

```
var gesturesX = 0;
var gesturesY = 0;

var startPosition = 0;
var velocity = 0;
var isMouseDown = false;

var timer;

function GetVelocity() {
    velocity = startPosition - gesturesY;
}

$(document).mousemove( function (e) {
    gesturesX = parseInt(e.pageX, 10);
    gesturesY = parseInt(e.pageY, 10);
    $("#mouse").html(gesturesY);
    if (isMouseDown) {
        window.scrollBy(0, startPosition - gesturesY);
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).mousedown( function() {
    startPosition = gesturesY;
    isMouseDown = true;
    timer = window.setTimeout(GetVelocity, 50);
});

$(document).mouseup( function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
    if (velocity != 0) {
        $Body = $("body");
        var distance = velocity * 20;
        var scrollToPosition = $Body.scrollTop() + distance;
        $Body.eq(0).animate({ scrollTop: scrollToPosition}, 1000);
        velocity = 0;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: wow, you're awesome man. if it's not too much trouble, is there a way to make it so when i release the mouse, if i'm still scrolling down the page, to have the page slowly animate to a stop? This is what i was in a way trying to create, but for the whole page: http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll it would be neat if ur code could see how fast the mouse is going on mouseup then glide to a stop with the length of the glide after mouseup being calculated by the mouse speed on mouseup, but if that's too much, then a predetermined stopping glide if the mouse is moving a certain speed on mouseup.

Comment: I get you... you could probably measure the initial velocity by taking a measure after a set time, then on mouseup you could continue the scroll for an amount relative to the velocity... I will have a play and get back to you!

Comment: I have a rough example working, I will update the example above. It will need to be played with to make it smooth!

Comment: BEAUTIFUL, i applied easing to it and it works pretttty good. the only bugs are, if you drag the scrollbar, or just click on it, it will stick you into drag mode so even if your mouse is up it will scroll according to your xy pos. then if you grab the screen with a non-moving mouse cursor, then try to flick it up or down, the screen will jump up and down, from the cursors new pos, to the pos when you first grabbed the screen. Not sure how to fix these but i'm gonna keep trying, here's where it's at currently: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/bQvV4/6/

Comment: The guy who made the plugin that I sent you the link for above, his plugin that does almost the exact same thing as what you've done here, is 12kb uncompressed.... yours is under 1kb..... now sure, this one needs refining and stuff... but... why the HUGE difference?

Comment: I guess to be fair to that developer, his also handles horizontal scrolling, it is wrapped in a jQuery Plugin and it is smooth - we will see how big ours is once we're done ;)

Comment: I have had a fiddle - to make it visible in JS Fiddle I am doing it on a div, rather than the entire document. The velocity is measured throughout the drag, which makes it smoother. I still need to sort the scrollbar click being treated as a drag... http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/avDYX/

Comment: I have updated it for three things... firstly, it is now a jQuery plugin. Secondly, I've fixed the scroll-bar issue. Thirdly, I have stopped text being selected when you are trying to drag-scroll. It is at the same place: http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/avDYX/

Comment: Hey man if I could ask you one final question: how did you fix the scrollbar problem? i'm trying to figure out what the fix was.

Comment: It's not a brilliant fix, but it works. I wrapped the content in a spare division, all the events fire off of the inner division, but the scrollbar belongs to the outer division. That is why the scrollbar no longer fires the events. You can use the same idea for applying the effect to the entire body by wrapping it in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix for the scrollbar problem: use $(document.body) instead of $(document).

Still, the animation behave strangely sometimes, especially with repetitive scrolls. (eg. scrolling up and the following animation scrolls down).

Since the OP asked for a PDF viewer-like scrolling (and not an iPhone-like scrolling) that don't involve any kind of animation, I guess we could put Sohnee's code on a diet and write this:

```
    var gesturesY = 0;
    var startPosition = 0;
    var isMouseDown = false;

    $(document.body).mousemove( function (e) {
        gesturesY = parseInt(e.pageY, 10);
        if (isMouseDown) {
            window.scrollBy(0, startPosition - gesturesY);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $(document.body).mousedown( function() {
        startPosition = gesturesY;
        isMouseDown = true;
    });

    $(document.body).mouseup( function() {
        isMouseDown = false;
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation of [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878959/francesco)'s answer that includes scrolling along the X-axis:

```
$(function ()
{

  var   gesturesX = 0
    ,   gesturesY = 0
    ,      startX = 0
    ,      startY = 0
    , isMouseDown = false

  $(document.body).mousemove(function (e)
  {

    gesturesX = parseInt(e.pageX, 10)

    gesturesY = parseInt(e.pageY, 10)

    if (isMouseDown)
    {

      window.scrollBy(startX - gesturesX, startY - gesturesY)

      return false

    }

  }
  )

  $(document.body).mousedown(function ()
  {

    startX = gesturesX

    startY = gesturesY

    isMouseDown = true

    return false

  }
  )

  $(document.body).mouseup(function ()
  {

    isMouseDown = false

    return false

  }
  )

}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define CSS classes to set cursor like pdf reader, closed hand when dragging to scroll and open hand when not scrolling.

```
.closehand {
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/closedhand.cur), default !important;
}
.openhand {
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Define a div on page where the content to scroll is placed, and attach to event listeners. In the example (Variation of  [Francesco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878959/francesco)'s answer) I use **#draggable** to link the div. **mousemove** will cause drag. *mousedown* will detect user starting scroll. **click** will detect user completing drag. 
*I tried **mouseup** but that let the page snap back to initial position.*

**mouseout** detects if user moves out of scrollable area while still holding mouse down.

```
var gesturesY = 0;
    var startPosition = 0;
    var isMouseDown = false;

    $('#draggable').mousemove( function (e) {
        gesturesY = parseInt(e.pageY, 10);
        if (isMouseDown) {
        $(this).removeClass('openhand');
        $(this).addClass('closehand');      
            window.scrollBy(0, startPosition - gesturesY);
            return false;
        }

    });

    $('#draggable').mousedown( function() {

        startPosition = gesturesY;
        isMouseDown = true;
        return false;
    });

    $('#draggable').click( function() {
        $(this).removeClass('closehand');
        $(this).addClass('openhand');
        isMouseDown = false;
        return false;
    });
    $('#draggable').mouseout( function() {
        $(this).removeClass('closehand');
        $(this).addClass('openhand');
        isMouseDown = false;
        return false;
    });
```